# Separate alignment for 2 div elements on the same line

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have the weather data, humidity, and wind speed set on the same line as min-, and max-, temps respectively, see below:

[image]

However, I tried to align the temps to the right, and the humidity and wind speed to the left, but it doesn't seem to let me.

```css
.extra_info_1,
.extra_info_2 {
  text-align: left;
}

.min_temp,
.max_temp {
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
}

.humidity,
.wind {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="extra_info_1">
  <div class="humidity">Humidity: N/A</div>
  <div class="min_temp">N/A</div>
  <br>
</div>

<div class="extra_info_2">
  <div class="wind">Wind speed: N/A</div>
  <div class="max_temp">N/A</div>
</div>
```

**JS (I don't think this is needed but here you are anyway):**

```js
document.querySelector(".min_temp").innerText = "Min temp: " + temp_min + "°C";
document.querySelector(".max_temp").innerText = "Max temp: " + temp_max + "°C";

document.querySelector(".feels_like").innerText = "Feels like: " + feels_like + "°C" 
document.querySelector(".humidity").innerText = "Humidity: " + humidity + "%";
```

Comment: Are you particularly tied to that HTML structure? Semantically, I'd personally restructure into a list (`<ol>` or `<ul>`, as appears more appropriate), with `<li>` elements to contain the text and details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to align 2 items to opposite sides of a div, you can utilize [CSS Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp), or more specifically, the [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) property of Flexbox.

```css
.extra_info_1, .extra_info_2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="extra_info_1">
    <div class="humidity">Humidity: N/A</div>
    <div class="min_temp">Min temp: N/A</div>
</div>

<div class="extra_info_2">
    <div class="wind">Wind speed: N/A</div>
    <div class="max_temp">Max temp: N/A</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have targeted the 2 containers, and have applied `display: flex`, and `justify-content: space-between`. Let me explain each of these lines.

In Flexbox, you have [Flex containers](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_container.asp) and [Flex items](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_items.asp).

In your case, since I have applied `display: flex;` to the `.extra_info_1` and `.extra_info_2` divs, I have made those Flex containers, and all their direct children elements are Flex items.

Lastly, I used the `justify-content: space-between` to split the free space in the Flex containers between the Flex items, or the text, in your case.

If you would like to read more about Flexbox, I recommend reading [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) by the Mozilla Developer Network.